# Emitting custom events on components

Tags: vuejs2

I am following Component Basics guide on [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event), but I cannot produce the result as guided. I don't know whether to put the `methods` property on component or on root Vue instance.

When I put method `onIncreaseCount` inside component, an error is thrown.

[image: error]

But when I put method `onIncreaseCount` inside root Vue instance, although there is no error, nothing is applied when I click the button.

```
// JS
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function(){ return {count: 0} }
    template: `<button v-on:click="$emit('increase-count')">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>`,
    methods: {
        onIncreaseCount: function(){ this.count++ }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: "#main"
})
// HTML
<main class="main" id="main">
    <button-counter title="Example component" @increase-count="onIncreaseCount"></button-counter>
</main>
```

I expect the `{{ count }}` value will be increased each time I click the button, but it doesn't change.

Comment: Read documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 2):

you don't need any emit jsut you have to call the increase function

handle in component itself

```
// JS
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function(){ return {count: 0} }
    template: `<button v-on:click="increaseCount">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>`,
    methods: {
        increaseCount: function(){ this.count++ }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: "#main"
})
// HTML
<main class="main" id="main">
    <button-counter title="Example component"></button-counter>
</main>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like I misunderstood the concept of emitting. It is used to communicate between the component and the parent instance (parent component or in this guide, the root instance).